# how put save button above a div

Tags: html, css

I need to put a div with a id under a save button. This is html code:

```
<button id="item_new" data-action="create" class="floating-button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
       <i class="material-icons">save</i>
     </button>
```

and this is my `<div>`:

```
<div id="least">
```

In this way the div hides the button and my purpose is show the button above the div. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to explain the problem? The given statements doesn't have enough information to understand the issue like CSS, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It's better to show all your code and maybe a plunkr or jsfiddle.  That said, I'll guess that your "floating-button" class applies a CSS float style to the button (probably float left).  Float styles make their elements not take up specific space in the DOM rendering so your doc winds up on top.  There are a lot of options for fixing it depending on your goal, the simplest being to remove that CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Add div section & add the following code

style="clear:both"

before & after your button in div.

I hope it works.

Comment: <div style="clear:both"></div><button id="item_new" data-action="create" class="floating-button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
   <i class="material-icons">save</i>
 </button>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="least"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below CSS code to your page.

```
#item_new
{
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

add div with style clear:both; in between Button and div

```
<button id="item_new" data-action="create" class="floating-button mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
   <i class="material-icons">save</i>
 </button>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="least"></div>
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: That will solve his problem at the cost of adding junk markup